# Wear 2 app installation times out on watch

Tags: android, google-play, wear-os

We have a Android Wear app since a couple of years. Previously packaged in the phone apk.

Now we want to release different apks for phone, wear 1 and wear 2 and have problems with the app not installing on the wear 2 device (using Google Internal testing).

We have followed:
https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging

From the wear apps build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId '<same as on phone>'
    minSdkVersion 23
}

productFlavors {
    wear1 {
        dimension "default"
        versionCode getVersionCodeForWear(1, defaultConfig.minSdkVersion)
    }
    wear2 {
        dimension "default"
        def minSdk = 25
        minSdkVersion minSdk
        versionCode getVersionCodeForWear(2, minSdk)
    }
}
```

`wearAppUnbundled true` are set in the phones build.gradle.

It does work installing the app on the watch with adb.
Wear 1 build installs on wear 1 watch.

But it won't install on wear 2 watch from google play, opening Google Play on the watch finds the app, installations starts but always times out after a while. No clear error message is given.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Can you add to your question any information from Google Play in your Logcat? It always has the tag "Phonesky"

Comment: Log showed:
E: Commit of session 895770994 failed: Package /data/app/vmdl895770994.tmp/<appId> has no certificates at entry AndroidManifest.xml
E: Error -504 while installing <appId>: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Package /data/app/vmdl895770994.tmp/<appId> has no certificates at entry AndroidManifest.xml
E: Package install failed <appId> errorCode -504

But the real problem was actually that the google account used for internal testing was not activated for testing. After activating the user the app installed.